# Explain me the execution time difference

Tags: go, benchmarking

I've started learning Golang with Donovan-Kernighan "The Go Programming Language" book. In chapter 1 the author advises to test several alternative simple echo function implementations. I used `time` function to calculate execution time like this:

```golang
  29 func main() {
  30     var start, end int64
  31     //fmt.Println("Testing echo implementation")
  32     start = time.Now().UTC().UnixNano()
  33     echo3()
  34     end = time.Now().UTC().UnixNano()
  35     fmt.Println(end - start)
  36     start = time.Now().UTC().UnixNano()
  37     echo3()
  38     end = time.Now().UTC().UnixNano()
  39     fmt.Println(end - start)
  40 }
```

And in case I build code with `go build ...` command I get the result:

```
➜  go-hello-world ./echo2
./echo2
81073
./echo2
5591
```

As you can see the first call require ten times bigger amount of time compare to second one. Note that I call the same `echo3` function in both cases. I guessed that the first call of `fmt.Println` required to much time. For this purpose I've added function call in line 31 and tested again:

```
➜  go-hello-world ./echo2
Testing echo implementation
./echo2
6327
./echo2
4249
```

**You can see that both calls require similar amount of time.**

**But where is a source of truth?**

Another one interesting moment is that when I run my code by `go run ...` command I get much smaller amount of time:

```
➜  go-hello-world go run echo2.go
Testing echo implementation
/tmp/go-build040243191/b001/exe/echo2
1743
/tmp/go-build040243191/b001/exe/echo2
1133
➜  go-hello-world go run echo2.go
/tmp/go-build646239204/b001/exe/echo2
34525
/tmp/go-build646239204/b001/exe/echo2
1133
```

I thought when I make a binary with build command I get more effective machine code for execution. **Could you please explain me why it works in this way in practice.**

Environment:

```
OS: ArchLinux 5.2.5-arch1-1-ARCH
Go: go1.12.7 linux/amd64
```

*P.S. I'm sorry for my English.*

**UPD#1**

`echo3` code:

```
  20 func echo3() {
  21     s, sep := "", ""
  22     for _, arg := range os.Args[:] {
  23         s += sep + arg
  24         sep = " "
  25     }
  26     fmt.Println(s)
  27 }
```

**UPD#2**

```
➜  go-hello-world go run echo2.go
/tmp/go-build573021176/b001/exe/echo2
13019
/tmp/go-build573021176/b001/exe/echo2
1067
/tmp/go-build573021176/b001/exe/echo2
955
/tmp/go-build573021176/b001/exe/echo2
987
```

and

```
➜  go-hello-world ./echo2          
./echo2
199681
./echo2
19404
./echo2
5965
./echo2
4803
./echo2
4673
./echo2
8244
```

Comment: @CeriseLimón in UPD#1 section at the end

Comment: Measuring them this way is unlikely to offer valuable insight. Write proper benchmarks using the `testing` package and see what results you get.

Comment: Instead of twice, try measuring it 4 times and see if a pattern appears.   There is likely some lazy-state construction that happens on the first run, but is re-used for subsequent ones.

Comment: @Adrian, I realize that I have to use `testing` package to get correct values. But I'm looking for explanation of described case. I'm afraid that this kind of behavior will be reproduced later, for example if I create some kind of microservice. I'll try to calculate execution time by external tool to compare and show you result later.

Comment: Trying to explain it would be pointless; the test is so microscopic and executed so few times that the data you get from it tells you absolutely nothing. That's why I would suggest writing a proper benchmark to get real data.

Comment: @mevets see UPD#2. It seems you're right. Do you have any idea why the binary is 10 times slower than `go run` sandbox?

Comment: I get your point, thank you, @Adrian

Comment: on go version go1.10 darwin/amd64, I saw 37480,3056,2831,2768 for both "go build" and "go run".

Comment: btw, if you uncomment your first Println, the numbers smooth out a bit; the first one is the time taken to plumb fmt.Print()....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing a benchmark method with a loop running each method a few hundred times or so using the benchmark techniques shown in section 11.4.

The discrepancies between runs might be various measurement errors caused by a multitasking operating system and timer resolution and such.

Also, I think it´s ok to go back to exercises when you are further along (The exercise expects some familiarity with the topic)